# Object of type type is not JSON serializable [DJango Rest Framework]

Tags: django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

i'm using django restframework
here's my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles
# Create your models here.

LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted([(item, item) for item in get_all_styles()])

class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,default="")
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default="friendly", max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default="friendly", max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["created"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

this is the views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Snippet
from .serializers import SnippetSerializer

# Create your views here.

class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer

class SnippetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
```

and this is the urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from snippets import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("snippets", views.SnippetList.as_view()),
    path("snippets/<int:pk>", views.SnippetDetail.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

so when I try to run the http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets in the browser I get this error:
Object of type type is not JSON serializable.

here's a screenshot of the same:
[image]

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Snippet model, you have defined `linenos` as a **BooleanField**, but it's not defined correctly. The correct way to define a **BooleanField** is by calling it as a function with the default argument:

```
linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

You missed the parentheses, so it's treated as a class attribute without a default value, and this can lead to issues with JSON serialization.

Make this change in your Snippet model and then run the migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```